# Достать номер из текста

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, строки

Дан текст, в нём есть номер телефона, может быть как мобильный, так и "домашний", определенного формата нет, длина тоже может быть разной, например могут быть варианты:

xx-xx-xx

xxx-xxx

xxx-xx-xx

8(xxx)-xxx-xx-xx

8xxxxxxxxxx

И так далее

Возникает вопрос, как их достать, думаю пользоваться regex но прописать все варианты думаю если и возможно, то их очень много

**EDIT 1**

В тексте так же могут быть и другие цифры помимо номера, сейчас пока перебираю все возможные варианты записи номера для записи в regex.

Один из вариантов - удалить все тире и скобки и найти самую длинную цифру. Удалить не так сложно, сложнее найти самое длинное число в строке. Как это можно реализовать?

**EDIT 2**

Вот пример, в примере домашний номер телефона, однако может быть и мобильный, записанный в любом формате

Продолжается набор в группу "ПАРИКМАХЕР 3 разряда"!!!5 марта начинается курс обучения

Парикмахерские курсы включают в себя полную теоретическую и практическую подготовку, необходимую для трудоустройства и работы по специальности «парикмахер». Ученики парикмахерских курсов за короткое время научатся выполнять модные современные стрижки, освоят технологии завивки, укладки и окрашивания волос, смогут познакомиться с новейшими технологиями и тенденциями в области парикмахерского искусства..\nПредварительная запись Иваново, ул. Хакасская, 27\n34-40-80

**EDIT 3**

Указал я не все варианты, так же может использоваться +7, в скобках может быть 3, а не 4 цифры. То есть вариантов может быть огромное количество, и я пытаюсь подобрать универсальный вариант для всех. Как вариант можно сделать так

```
string s = "Парикмахерские курсы включают в себя полную теоретическую и практическую подготовку, необходимую для трудоустройства и работы по специальности «парикмахер». Ученики парикмахерских курсов за короткое время научатся выполнять модные современные стрижки, освоят технологии завивки, укладки и окрашивания волос, смогут познакомиться с новейшими технологиями и тенденциями в области парикмахерского искусства..\nПредварительная запись Иваново, ул. Хакасская, 27 34-40-80"
s.Replace("-", String.Empty);
s.Replace("(", String.Empty);
s.Replace(")", String.Empty);
```

Тогда получится в тексте будет номер без лишних знаков, минимальная длинна 4 символа, как его найти?

Comment: Хорошо бы еще пример входных данных. Что-то типа: "Вася, 25 лет, 8(555)555555, образование 3 класса, желаемая зарплата 300 тыщ".

Comment: Разбить текст на слова, если в слове доминируют цифры, то оставить только цифры.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

приведенные вами форматы телефона

```
    string input = "tel 1 11-22-33 tel 2 444-555 tel 3 666-77-88 55 8(999)-111-22-33 55 81234567891";
    string pattern = "[+()0-9-]{5,20}";

    var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

    foreach (Match match in matches)
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
    Console.WriteLine();
```

Вывод:

```
11-22-33
444-555
666-77-88
8(999)-111-22-33
81234567891
```

При этом шаблоне `var pattern = @"\b(\d.?){6,}\b";` 
У меня получился вывод:

```
1 11-22-33
2 444-555 
3 666-77-88
55 8(999
111-22-33 55
81234567891
```

Comment: Хорошо, но не совсем: ваш паттерн сматчит подряд идущие скобки, плюсы, тире. То есть, например, `-----` тоже будет поймано.

Answer (score 2):

Просто удалите все не-цифры из строки:

```
string source = "123(3312)+312";
string number =  new string(source.ToCharArray().Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

Comment: Но в задании не сказано что в тексте не может быть других цифр.... Думаю, все же, правильнее будет задать все нужные форматы и искать регексом.

Comment: Могут быть другие цифры... К сожалению

Comment: @Actticus Тогда в вопросе необходимо указывать такие важные детали. Обновите его и добавьте то, что вы уже пробовали, объясните, что работает, что нет.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew я один тип решения нашёл, но так как он очень энергоёмкий попросил помочь найти более лёгкое решение

Answer (score 0):

В приведенных вами вариантах номеров телефонов между цифрами может находиться один нецифровой символ (скобки или тире). В тексте могут быть и другие числа, поэтому вам нужно найти длинное: я ввел лимит в 6 цифр.

```
var input = "Вася, 25 лет, 8(555)555555, образование 3 класса, желаемая зарплата 300 тыщ";
var pattern = @"\b(\d.?){6,}\b";

var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

foreach (Match match in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
```

Вывод:

```
8(555)555555
```

Возможно, проверять границы слова не нужно, тогда можно убрать `\b`.

---

В шаблоне `@"(\d.?){6,}"` из-за наличия точки `.` ловится любой символ между цифрами. Можно улучшить вероятность нахождения нужной информации, использовав набор нужных символов:

```
@"(\d[()-]?){6,}"
```

или, если в номере телефона могут идти более одного нецифрового символа подряд, например, `8(999)-111-22-33`, тогда:

```
@"(\d[()-]{0,2}){6,}"
```